# JSON Unicode doen't work or phpMyAdmin?

Tags: json, unicode

I Searched in the web especially stackoverflow but my problem didn't resolved.

Im trying to get JSON from database but it shows question sign (?)

```
[{"task_id":"13","task_title":"???","task_desc":"??? ???","task_done":"0"}]
```

I set DB collation to utf8_persian_ci;
but it didnt work for me.
I used this php codes but they didnt worked for me:

- mysql_set_charset('utf8'); (didn't worked)
- set DB collation to utf8_persian_ci (didn't worked)
- header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');(didn't worked)
- function escapeJsonString($value) {
  $escapers = array("\", "/", "\"", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\x08", "\x0c");
  $replacements = array("\\", "\/", "\\"", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\f", "\b");
  $result = str_replace($escapers, $replacements, $value);
  return $result;
  }
- echo my_json_encode($output , **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE**);(error : Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - assumed 'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE' in E:\dev\project\web\note-server\service.php on line 57 )